# webKit Transitions on Dynamic DOM Element

Tags: jquery, html, css, webkit, css-transitions

I my CSS file I define my `div` class for transitions:

```
div.BlackOut {
 -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

Then, in my javascript add a dynamic dom element (via jQuery):

```
var cssObj = {
   'background-color' : '#000',
   'width' : '100%',
   'height' : '400px',
   'position' : 'absolute',
   'top' : 0,
   'z-index' : '9998'
  };
var element = $("<div>").css(cssObj).addClass('BlackOut').appendTo( 'body' );
element.get(0).style.opacity = 0;
```

But the transition doesn't start!

Why?

Comment: Here $("<div>"), it looks incorrect. It should be $("div").

Comment: @Satya the $("<div>") statement is correct, that is how you quickly create new items - in this case a <div>. But to be correct. the tag needs to be closed: $("<div></div>"); or $("<div />");

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same problem, and found that my transformations would occur, but the transition would not run - no animation.  It appears that if you try to execute the transitions before the element is in the DOM, it will ignore the transitions - while still executing the transformation.  I don't know enough to say whether that's a bug or according to spec.

Anyway, if your new element is an image, you could add your transitions/css class via the `load` event.

However, I was unable to find an event that fires when sans-url elements are added to the DOM.  I chose to fall back on a timeout, which should work for you as well.

Your code would look something like this:

```
var element = $("<div id='BlackOutDiv'></div>").css(cssObj).appendTo( 'body' );
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#BlackOutDiv').addClass('BlackOut');
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an easing or perhaps an `opacity`. So:

```
div.BlackOut {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
}
```

That should work, but maybe you also would want to future proof your css, to also include other browsers (FF 4 for example):

```
div.BlackOut {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
     -khtml-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
         -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
            transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
}
```